# Why is my Kenmore 800 washer not completing the spin cycle?

Tags: plumbing

I have a Kenmore 800 washer, about three years old. When I start the load, and set it to the normal setting as usual, instead of the two second delay before it starts filling with water, it sounds like it's immediately going into a fill and agitate.   When the cycle has completed, including spin, the clothes are still soaking wet.  It helps if I set it to spin again, but they are still not getting as dried out as they should.  This started the same time that I noticed the whole cycle started funny.  What could this be?  Timer?  Pump??

Comment: I would think the timer is messed up, personally.

Comment: Pump filter is clean? Do you hear the pump working while spinning? Does the spin go at normal spin speed and duration?